# Implement Download listener for webView inside Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm using below code to populate my Fragments with webView. I would like to download any file from external browser whenever user clicks any download link inside webView.

I know for Mainactivity, Below Code Works Fine.

```html
 webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
                {
                    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength)
                    {
                        //download file using web browser
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });
```

But I would like to implement for Fragments , How can I achieve this.

My Fragment  code is

```html
package com.nepalpolice.cdp;



import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


/**
 * Created by Sagar on 2017/09/23. yo chai menupage ko Fragments ko lagi
 */

public class webb extends Fragment {

    WebView myWebView;
    private LinearLayout container;
    private Button nextButton, closeButton;
    private EditText findBox;
    ProgressBar pbar;

    public webb() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webb, container,  false);



        String url1 = getArguments().getString("url1");


        myWebView=(WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        pbar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        myWebView.setInitialScale(1);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();


        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl(url1);

        return rootView;


    }

    public static String changedHeaderHtml(String htmlText) {

        String head = "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=yes\" /></head>";

        String closedTag = "</body></html>";
        String changeFontHtml = head + htmlText + closedTag;
        return changeFontHtml;

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //remove your progressdialog here
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the url clicked inside the webview by overriding *shouldOverrideUrlLoading* method in your WebViewClient

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 

        // download your stuff here

        return false;
    }
```

be sure to read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) and to override correct  *shouldOverrideUrlLoading* method, depending on which SDK Api number you are targeting with your app!

cheers

Comment: @Pitor Z, when I cut and paste    myWebView.loadUrl(url1);, it throws error but if i replace url instead of url1.........., then only it doesn't work. But I would like to load the url1 which passes from another fragment as string...How can I load string then??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Download listener,

```
            mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDescription,
                                    String mimetype, long contentLength) {//code here}
```